# Using Azure AD for Amazon RDS for PostgreSQL Authentication

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, azure-active-directory, amazon-rds

What is the best way to authenticate users on Amazon RDS for PostgreSQL using Azure AD? This can be done using Amazon RDS and Active Directory and Amazon Directory Services, but I was unable to find a solution for Azure AD.

Comment: You have mentioned AWS Managed AD. You can use it to connect to Azure AD, no? Then this [article](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/using-external-kerberos-authentication-with-amazon-rds-for-postgresql/) explains how to join RDS into the domain.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think connecting between AWS Manage AD and Azure AD is only possible with Azure AD being set as the secondary domain controller. In my case Azure AD must remain the primary domain controller, so this may not be an option.

Comment: You mean you need a one way trust, with Azure AD as the trusted domain? Based on this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/directoryservice/latest/admin-guide/ms_ad_tutorial_setup_trust_create.html) I thought it is possible? Quote, "AWS Managed Microsoft AD also supports external trusts."